# Sign in with AngularFireAuth signInWithPopup when user is disabled return "internal Error"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm building an App with Angular 4 (4.4.3) and AngularFire2 (4.0.0-rc.2).
I have made a service to login using Google and Facebook sign-in method which works perfectly in normal conditions.

I'm looking for a way to give feedback to a user trying to log-in when he/she is disabled (you can disable users in Firebase Console). There's nothing in the docs about it.

Also, when you try to sign in using a disable account, using `signInWithPopup`, it returns an 'Internal Error'. This is not the expected behaviour.

This is the login snippet:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(credential =>  {
    // manage credentials
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      // error =  {code: "auth/internal-error", message: "An internal error has occurred."}
    });
```

**Does anybody knows a way to get a proper response?**

Comment: This seems like a bug. I have reported this to the Firebase Auth team.

Comment: Thanks. My guess is that it's more related to AngularFire2 than to Firebase. 
I'll drop an issue in their Github

Comment: No, it's a Firebase-auth issue. AngularFire2 just wraps that method.